# Debian: chgrp doesn't works properly on home folder

Tags: debian, group

I'm trying to use `chgrp` on a folder named "share" in a home folder of the user "2".  The `ls -l` presents the folder like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 2 bin 4096 Sep 29 13:09 share
```

When using `chgrp` with the group named "34" on the folder "share" as presented above, the "bin" parameter changes to 34, but the group parameter (which is 2 right now) stays the same.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The first `2` represent total number of hard links and then second `2` is your user and then group name either `bin` or `34` after you changes.

Comment: this is a great example for why usernames should be name-like and not single digits.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the first `2` with your user `2`. The first `2` represent total number of hard links and then second `2` is your user and then group name either bin or `34` after you changes. Here is the explanation of what you see:

```
  +-permissions that apply to the owner
  |
  |     +-permissions that apply to all other users
  |     |
  |     |  +-number of hard links
  |     |  |
  |     |  |         +-size      +-last modification date and time
 _|_   _|_ |       __|__    _____|_______
drwxr-xr-x 2 2 bin 4096     Sep 29  13:09 share
    ___      _ ___                        _____
     |       |  |                           |
     |       |  |                           +-name of file or directory
     |       |  |
     |       |  +-the group that the group permissions applies to
     |       |
     |       +-owner
     |
     +-permissions that apply to users who are members of the group
```